# How to calculate distance between two points given in a .txt file?

Tags: python

I have a .txt file that has x,y at the top with 10,5 and 4,2 below it as the x,y points. I was wondering how I could manipulate the text file so I could calculate the euclidean distance between the points. I am stuck on how I should read, split, or strip the text file.

Comment: Hi, it's useful if you send a sample of the textfile, as no we have no clue how things are formatted. In general however, you can use split(delimiter) to split a string based on the delimiter, if you use a for loop, you can proably get the info you need.

Comment: Could you share some of your code you already have? Basically you read the first line, split it on `,`, then you read the second line and split it on `,`. Then you use Pythagoras to calculate the distance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way

```
def euclidean(x,y):
    return ((abs(int(x[0])-int(y[0]))**2)+(abs(int(x[1])-int(y[1])))**2)


f = open('1.txt')
data = f.readlines()
euclidean(data[0].rstrip('\n').split(','),data[1].rstrip('\n').split(','))
#rstrip is  to remove the `\n` at the end of string
```